# Can I call arbitrary functions in RDD.map operation in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Lets say I have a dataset of 1000,000 rows. I split it into groups of 400 rows. 
I convert them into rdd with 1000,000 / 400 = 2500 `rdd` elements such that the 400 rows are concatenated horizontally.

Now my question is can I call arbitrary function within a map operation on rdd.

```
rdd.map(ele => {
someFunction(ele)
}) 

def someFunction(){
   step 1 : restucture the `ele` back into 400 rows to their
            original format (somehow magically) to create arguments
            for SVM kernel based classifiers
   step 2 : call a function like SVM function with that restructured data
   step 3 : return the result
}
```

SVM is a kernel based classifier taken from [SMILE](http://haifengl.github.io/classification.html#svm) library here.

The reason I am doing this is because Spark only has inbuilt LinearSVM classifer but not other kernel based classifiers. So hopefully, after jumping through the hoops, I should be able to call the kernel SVM classifier in a distributed manner taking advantage of Spark

Is this possible? Is it a recommended way? What pitfalls does it have? Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are the `x` and `y` for your `knn` coming from? Remember when you're mapping, it's running over each data element separately. Is each item in the `rdd` a separate dataset you want to run `knn` on, or do you want `knn` over the `rdd`?

Comment: Generally speaking there is no reason you can not call a arbitrary function as long as it follows the general spark guidelines. There are many spark extensions that provide such functionality. However as @Ethan suggested, map is a one-to-one transformation that will apply the function to each element separately, so it will not pass in all 400 rows to someFunction() but only one row.

Comment: You might want to look into this https://github.com/saurfang/spark-knn

Comment: @Ethan : Yes, each item in the rdd is a separate dataset over which I need to run knn or kernel based svm. That's why I am concatenating all the 400 rows into a single element.

Comment: @sinanspd : The problem is I need to run SVM kernel based classifiers on the data subsets I create from the original data. Could you point me to the spark extensions which provide such functionality? KNN was an example, the real reason is SVM kernel based classifiers aren't present in spark.

Comment: Happy to try to find some examples. Just to be clear I was talking about libraries that implement functions on RDDs, not libraries that specifically solve your problem. They would just give some ideas on how to approach this. My best bet is you will have to wrap this SMILE function in a UDF or a custom spark native function. The tricky part here is the training, since you need to have all the data together. I think looking into UDAF (user defined aggregate functions) would be a good start. I am starting to feel like this is more a limitation on ML than spark.

Comment: I will read this : https://www.scs.stanford.edu/17au-cs244b/labs/projects/addair.pdf
Might give some ideas on a general sense on how to approach this further. Some patterns here might be translatable to spark

Comment: Is there something specific wrong with your sample? Just calling out to a foreign KNN function in a `rdd.map` should work fine, provided that it's thread safe and there's no state being set.

Comment: @Ethan : Could you explain a bit more as to what you mean by "there's no state being set"? Or better still, could you point me to a resource where I can read more about it to evaluate it myself. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to ask if you tried this, and if so what came out unexpected. I know nothing about the SMILE libraries, so I have no idea if they're tracking any sort of state internally or doing other non-threadsafe stuff, which might be messed up by the spark parallelism model.